# CodeIgniter Conditional - Multiple Tables

Tags: sql, codeigniter, if-statement

I'm stuck on the logic for a conditional that I need some help with.  I am building a project collaboration platform where users can view open projects and join them to form a team.  I've got the joining functionality working fine but I want to have a conditional set to not show the 'Join This Team' button if they are already a member of that project group.  I may already have some of what is needed to do this but I'm not entirely sure how to go about it.  (I had help writing the code I've already implemented)  Here is the code below for joining a project:

//controller

```
    public function join($project){

    // Set Var
    $email = $this->session->userdata('email');

    // Join User
    $this->project_model->join_project($project, $email);

    //Redirect to Project
    redirect('projects');

}
```

//functions in model to get the members already joined and insert

```
        public function get_team_members($id){

        $this->db->select('team_members.user_id, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.location');
        $this->db->from('team_members');
        $this->db->where('team_members.project_id', $id);
        $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = team_members.user_id');

        return $this->db->get()->result_array();

    }


    public function join_project($id, $email){

        // Get UserID
        $this->db->select('id');
        $this->db->from('users');
        $this->db->where('email', $email);
        $user = $this->db->get()->row_array();

        // Set Insert Data
        $data = array(

            'project_id' => $id,
            'user_id' => $user['id']

        );

        // Insert into Team DB
        $this->db->insert('team_members', $data);

    }
```

//view

```
<div class="large-4 columns widget">
        <div class="row collapse top-margin">
            <div class="large-4 columns"></div>
            <div class="large-8 column bottom-spacer">

<?php $link = base_url()."project/join/".$project['project_id']; ?>
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="button primary radius extrawide"><h5>Join this Team</h5></a>
            </div>
        </div>
```

//view for team members

```
foreach ($team as $member){ ?>

                <!-- Team Member #1 -->
                <div class="row collapse">
                    <div class="large-4 columns">
                        <img class="left" src="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/img/user.png" alt="user img">
                    </div>
                    <div class="large-8 columns member-name">
                        <p class="name"><strong><?php echo $member['first_name']." ".$member['last_name']; ?></strong></p>
                        <p><span><?php echo $member['location'];?></span></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php } ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You want to hide button if logged in user already joined in that team. Right?

Comment: where is the code to get the list of team(project)?

Comment: please add in question.

Comment: Are you storing user id in session?

Comment: No, I'm storing the email though, which you can probably discern from the code I've supplied.

Comment: As per updated code, you are listing the members of one team. So you are showing only one team members in a page. If logged in user exist in this team, need to hide the button. Right?

Comment: Yes, the application could have any number of projects with any number of respective team members made up of converted users.  Each project will have its own page and own team members.  And yes, if logged in user exists in the team (team_members table) then they shouldn't see the join button at all.

Comment: where is the button exist? is it above the member list or under the list?

Comment: Above the member listing.

Comment: did you try my solution?

Comment: I didn't.  If you are able to show me some code on how to implement your example I can give it a shot.

Comment: Added code for your question. please check.

Answer (score 0):

You can do with two method.

Method 1. Create function `is_team_member($user_email, $team_id)` in your model. If user exist, true will be return else false. Pass the returned value to view via controller. Based on the value you can hide the button with use of if condition.

Method 2. You can check the user email in view foreach loop. If `$email == $member["email"]`, set flag to hide button. But in this case, your button should be under the member list. Bur, as we discussed in comment, your member list is above list. So create a variable to store the foreach html content as string. you can run the foreach loop above the button and cho the content after the button. Now based on the flag, you can hide the button.

**Ex for method - 1:**

In Controller, Team member listing function.

```
public function index($team_id){

    // Set Var
    $email = $this->session->userdata('email');


    $data["team"] = $this->project_model->get_team_members($team_id);
    $data["is_joined_user"] = $this->project_model->is_team_members($team_id,$email);
    //load view
    $this->view->load("view_name", $data);
}
```

**In model:**

```
public function is_team_members($team_id,$email)
{
   $this->db->select('*');
   $this->db->from('team');
   $this->db->join('users', 'users.id = team.user_id');
   $this->db->where("user.email",$email);
   $res = $this->db->get();
   if($res->num_rows()>0)
      return true;
   else
     return false;   
}
```

**In view:**

```
<?php
if(! $is_joined_user)
{
?>

<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="button primary radius extrawide"><h5>Join this Team</h5></a>
<?php
}
?>
```